# Set a node to succeed a specific node under the same parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT file and it sets the SpecialChild under Parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="GrandParent">
        <xsl:element name="tns:{name()}" namespace="http://www.test.com/ComBase/eom/1.0/">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:if test = "count(SpecialChild) > 0">
                <SpecialChild>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="SpecialChild/*"/>
                </SpecialChild>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SpecialChild"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(.)) != ''">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I want it to be under OtherChild node instead of being always under the bottom.

Expected:

```
<Parent>
    <OtherChild></OtherChild>
    <SpecialChild></SpecialChild>
    <OtherInfo></OtherInfo>
</Parent>
```

Actual:

```
<Parent>
    <OtherChild></OtherChild>
    <OtherInfo></OtherInfo>
    <SpecialChild></SpecialChild>
</Parent>
```

What changes should I make to my XSLT to achieve it? Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It would probably help a lot to show your input XML here. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, please post an input XML for us to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way (untested, because there's no input to test it with):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GrandParent">
    <xsl:element name="tns:{name()}" namespace="http://www.test.com/ComBase/eom/1.0/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|OtherChild"/>
        <xsl:if test="SpecialChild">
            <SpecialChild>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="SpecialChild/*"/>
            </SpecialChild>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::OtherChild or self::SpecialChild)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SpecialChild"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:**
Your first and last template are conflicting; I have removed the last one.